# Email Alert on Custom Object

Tags: apex, workflow, email-alert

We have a custom object called Worklog.

This custom object (Worklog) has a custom field (Worklog_User__c) which is a lookup to an salesforce user.

This user should get a notification whenever a record is created for this custom object with him/her being the associated user in that lookup field (Worklog_User__c)

We are trying to use the out of the box (Workflow Rules -> Email Alerts) feature for this.

We are stuck because there is no provision available to specify the email of the worklog user.

I have attached the screenshot also..hope it helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFXcF.jpg

Can someone tell me whether I can use out of the box feature for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup fields to the user object should be available under '**Related User**', not '**User**'.

[image]

The available recipients in my example are all the custom user lookup fields I have on the account object.

Comment: Hi Ninja..Appreciate the answer..Just one more thing..Is it possible to reference a user lookup field in the parent object of this Worklog custom object ?.

Comment: I don't believe so no, but you could create an email field on the child and use a WFR rule to populate the email field of the child from the parent.

Comment: Accepted as the answer :)..Thanks and one last newbie question..I assume that in WF the Immediate Workflow Actions get executed in sequence am i right ?

Comment: Actually no, not necessarily.  The order is undefined and you cannot guarantee the order of execution.  :(

Comment: Hi Ninja - Thanks for help so far. What about this ?.
Step 1 - WF evaluation criteria will be whether email is populated and a checkbox (new field which I will create with default value as false) is false or not.
Step 2 - After the evaluation criteria there I assume that there will not be anymore evaluation
Step 3 - As one of the immediate WF actions, I will create an email alert
Step 4 - As one of the immediate WF actions, I will set the checkbox (mentioned in step1) as true
So WF will not be re-evaluated in this session I guess order of Step 3 & 4 should not be an issue.What do you think ?

Comment: Yikes.  I would honestly ask a new question so you have a bit more room to elaborate on the WFR you need help with.  This is will do two things.  1) allow more people to see the question and increases your chance of a solid answer and 2) help others with a similar problem as they cant see it in a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16285/discussion-between-risingphoenix-and-sfdc-ninja).